# How do I remove the outermost line from ggRadar plot?

Tags: r, ggraph

The outermost line on the ggRadar plot is not part of the range of values. Is it possible to remove that outer line somehow (and of course the "tip" of the radials that exceed the range of values)?

Here is the sample code where you can see an example

```
require(ggiraph)
ggRadar(data=iris,aes(group=Species))
```

Answer (score 0):

just set `grid.mid` and `grid.max` parameters to be same value and you should have it.